# Swift 2 public convenience dynamic variable string error

Tags: ios, variables, swift2

I m doing iOS swift2 app with menu and working success. But i want to change text value to string variable for menu items. My codes here.

```
public class MediumMenuItem: NSObject {
    public var title: String?
    public var completion: completionHandler?

    override private init() {
        super.init()
    }

    public convenience init(title: String, completion: completionHandler) {
        self.init()
        self.title = title
        self.completion = completion
    }
}
```

My navigation controller

```
   let item2 = MediumMenuItem(title: "Link 1") {
            let topStoriesViewController = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("Web1") as! WebViewController1
            self.setViewControllers([topStoriesViewController], animated: false)
        }
```

I want to change  **MediumMenuItem(title: "Link 1")**  to like;

**MediumMenuItem(title: title1)  // variable not "link1"**

Thanks for help.

TY

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved it self :)

Added

```
var title1 : String?
var title2 : String?
var title3 : String?

title1 = "Link 1";
title2 = "Link 2";
title3 = "Link 3";


let item2 = MediumMenuItem(title: title1!) {
```

Thanks :)